# pause shell output

Tags: emacs

In windows shell it's possible to pause the output just by selecting a text in the shell window (a QuickEdit mode must be enabled). The same is possible in the cygwin shell (again with a QuickEdit mode).

How can I pause the output in emacs shell?

I need to pause it because some tasks are very verbose and it's difficult to search the necessary text in a big buffer.

When I execute `M-x comint-stop-subjob` I get a message "No SIGTSTP support"

As an example try to pause the following:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec  cat {} ';'
```

Comment: Why do you need to pause the output? You can scroll the window and select text even if the output is coming.

Comment: Some tasks are very verbose. They can even print more output than a limit of my buffer and I dont' want ot increase the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked for, but `clone-buffer` will get you close to what you want. After binding it to a convenient key and running your find command, calling `clone-buffer` will copy the contents of the buffer to a new buffer. The find command in the original buffer keeps running, but the cloned buffer contains only the output of find up to the point that you cloned it.

You can invoke this command multiple times in the original window, giving you a series of stop points to examine. I don't know how to actually pause the original window though.

Note that the newly cloned buffers are fully functional shell buffers.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it does work! I'll wait some time before accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the job by pressing <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-z</kbd>. Then just enter `fg` to make it work again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got a message "No SIGTSTP support" and it continue to log

Comment: OK, so the process cannot be stopped. What about redirecting its output to a file, possibly showing (`grep`) only the lines you are interested in?

Comment: Well, sure it's possible. My question is more about how can it be done easily, ideally as in Windows shell where you can just select a text to pause.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about pausing the output, but you can presumably just narrow the buffer?

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> to narrow-to-region
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> to narrow-to-page
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to widen to full buffer

Comment: It's an interesting idea. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried with find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec  cat {} ';'